# Структура. БД. SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных

[image: дана структура бд]

Код напишу сам. Подскажите, что значат эти ключи, обвел в кружочки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P - primary key

F - foreign key

U - unique key

Когда нарисован ключик - это означает индекс. Правее написано имя индекса.

Как я понял из картинки, серый ключик означает (как правило, кластеризованный) индекс по primary key, желтый ключик - обычный (некластеризованный) индекс

Этого объяснения достаточно?

Comment: Да, теперь понятней будет. Благодарю.